# Joining JSON files into a dataframe using spark/scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join two json files together and transform into a DataFrame. The below code is printing out two DataFrames one for test_1.json and another for test_2.json However they aren't joining together.

This is the piece of code to join together : Can anyone spot what I have done wrong?

```
//CODE TO JOIN THE TWO JSON FILES TOGETHER

    users_df_2.join(users_df_1,"table").createOrReplaceTempView("new_table")

   val results = spark.sql("SELECT Scenerio, table, case WHEN gender = 'F' then 'Female' WHEN gender = 'M' then 'Male' END as gender from new_table")
```

```
package com.test.dataframe

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

object dataframe {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Apache Spark Application Started ...")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("Create DataFrame from json File")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    //Code Block 1 Starts Here
    val json_file_path = "/Users/Desktop/test_1.json"
    val users_df_1 = spark.read.json(json_file_path)

    users_df_1.show(10, true)
    users_df_1.printSchema()
    //Code Block 1 Ends Here

    //Code Block 2 Starts Here
    val json_multiline_file_path = "/Users/Desktop/test_2.json"

    val user_schema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("Scenerio", StringType, true),
      StructField("table", StringType, true)
    ))

    val users_df_2 = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").json(json_multiline_file_path)

    users_df_2.show(10, false)
    users_df_2.printSchema()
    //Code Block 2 Ends Here

    //CODE TO JOIN THE TWO JSON FILES TOGETHER

    users_df_2.join(users_df_1,"table").createOrReplaceTempView("new_table")

   val results = spark.sql("SELECT Scenerio, table, case WHEN gender = 'F' then 'Female' WHEN gender = 'M' then 'Male' END as gender from new_table")

    spark.stop()
    println("Apache Spark Application Completed.")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just put both of your files in there '/Users/Desktop/' and spark will read them in and combine them as long as the schemas are the same.

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", "true").json('/Users/Desktop/')
```

or put both file paths in a list:

```
val df = sc.read.json(file1, file2, ...)
```